# How to start batch file at power on pc

Tags: windows, batch-file, startup

I would need to start a batch script at boot before the user to log in with his credentials.

How could I do?

Thank you all

Comment: `autoexec.bat` :) in old windows versions.

Comment: Its been touched previously in this post http://superuser.com/questions/548192/how-can-i-start-a-batch-script-before-logging-in

Comment: You can use Microsoft's srvany, or the third-party NSSM.  (Google them.)  NSSM is more powerful.

Comment: Another solution would be to auto login on that account, and run the batch and finally call "rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation" to lock the workstation again .. Just an alternative

Comment: Looking at the answers, I now realize this question is unclear.  Firstly, do you want the script to run even if no user logs in at all?  Secondly, does the script have to finish running before the user is allowed to log in?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at this [How to launch a program before the shell (Explorer) starts.](http://windowsitpro.com/windows/jsi-tip-0470-how-launch-program-shell-explorer-starts)

If you want to start an application before the shell starts, you can add a value to the `Userinit` value in the registry. In this key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

There is a value named `Userinit`. Change it so your program is run before userinit.exe. For example, to start notepad before the shell/everything else is initialized:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe,C:\Windows\system32\userinit.exe

Use commas to separate the programs that should be started.

So the same thing for your batch file just add the absolute path instead of the notepad example

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit the system's registry, you can run regedit.exe and add browse to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices`. Add a new string value, with an arbitrary name, and the full batch path as value.

I think this will be executed every time Windows is booted. Not sure about if it will be run after awakening from an hibernation period.

Not to be mistaked with `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`, which happens every time any user logs in (thanks to  Harry Johnston), or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`, which happens every time a certain user logs in.

Comment: @Harry Johnston: Right. I've updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 keys that you can edit from the local registry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

If HKLM (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) is modified it will affect the entire machine, so the batch file will run no matter who logs in, while HKCU (HKEY_CURRENT_USER) will only affect the currently logged in user when the registry is modified. You can also add, modify or verify the current existance of either of the above keys from your batch file, just open a command prompt and type `REG /?` to view available commands.